# CSS list-style-type disk showing numbers

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Here is the link to my test site: http://aspenwebsites.com/echo/

Right there bellow the header I'm having a list. I'm re-styleing WP twenty-fourteen theme, which had list-style-type set to 'square'. If I replace the value with 'disk' , instead of disk I get numbers!

If I remove the specification all together I do get proper bullet points in my list. But why would I be getting numbers with having list-style-type  set to 'disk'?

Comment: its "disc" not 'disk', may be defaulting because of the mis-spelling

Comment: check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Comment: What browser? In Chrome I see squares with "square" and disks with "disc" or any other invalid type.  OK now I see the problem in Firefox. More to follow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Firefox bug. (I can't imagine anyone thinking it is a *feature*).
This code duplicates it:

```
    <ul style="list-style-type:oranges">
      <li>apples</li>
      <li>bananas</li>
    </ul>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

***>>> EDIT: It's a feature***

As others have said, your solution is to replace "disk" with "disc".

Here is some background: It has been reported, and they don't want to fix it:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027647

based on a misinterpretation of:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-counter-styles-3/#extending-css2

which says that invalid list-style-types should default to "decimal". That makes sense for ordered lists, but not unordered lists.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is very helpful. It didn't even occur to me to check if other browsers were having same issue or not.